# Why the print(copy_dic) is {'a' : 3}?

Tags: python

I have learned python since 2 weeks ago.
But I don't understand why `copy_dic` is `{'a': 3}`.

save memory address ?? I don't know..

1: Case of Variable

```
var_a = 1

copy_var = var_a
var_a = 3

print(copy_var)
# 1
```

2: Case of Dictionary

```
dic = {'a':1}

copy_dic = dic
dic['a'] = 3

print(copy_dic)
# {'a': 3}
```

Comment: In Python `=` creates (new) references to an object. It does not create copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python names are just references to objects. When you have something like:

```
var_a = 1
dic = {'a' : 1}
```

`dic` and `var_a` are just names pointing to the respective objects.

visual representation:

```
var_a   -->     1
dic     -->  {'a' : 1}
```

And when you assign some other variable using `=` operator, what you are essentially doing is asking that other variable to point to **the same exact** object:

```
copy_var = var_a
copy_dic = dic
```

visual representation:

```
var_a   -->      1     <-- copy_var
dic     -->  {'a' : 1} <-- copy_dic
```

---

Now, changing that object affects all of the variables pointing to it, as is demonstrated in the question:

```
dic['a'] = 3
```

visual representation:

```
var_a   -->      1     <-- copy_var
dic     -->  {'a' : 3} <-- copy_dic
```

As can be seen, the single `dict` object both variables (`dic`, `copy_dic`) were pointing to is altered, and both of them still point to this object.

---

One question remains, *"Why changing changing the `int` object didn't have the same effect? Shouldn't operations on `var_a` affect `copy_var` too?"*
The answer is, in Python integers, strings, tuples and some other objects are *immutable*, meaning you cannot alter them. When you try to alter an integer like:

```
var_a = 3
```

or

```
var_a += 2
```

`var_a` starts pointing to an entirely different integer object.

visual representation:

```
var_a   -->      3
                 1     <-- copy_var
dic     -->  {'a' : 3} <-- copy_dic
```

---

What if you want to have separate `dict` objects? You can use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20copy#dict.copy) method:

```
dic = {'a':1}

copy_dic = dic.copy()  #   <-- notice `.copy` here
dic['a'] = 3

print(dic)
print(copy_dic)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 3}
{'a': 1}
```

`copy` creates a new copy of that object and returns it.
visual representation:

```
var_a   -->      3
                 1     <-- copy_var
dic     -->  {'a' : 1}
             {'a' : 1} <-- copy_dic
```

Be warned:

> ## copy()
>
> Return a shallow copy of the dictionary.

What is a *shallow copy*, one might ask. As the documentation states:

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

Meaning the `dict` objects are two different objects but their components are the same, thus if their objects were mutable, and you altered them, that would still affect the other one:

```
dic = {'a' : [1, 2]}    #  lists are mutable
copy_dic = dic.copy()

dic['a'].append("spam") #  <-- alters the object both of the dictionaries hold a reference to

print(dic)
print(copy_dic)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 'spam']}
{'a': [1, 2, 'spam']}
```

If you need to avoid that behavior, what you need is [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function:

> ## copy.deepcopy(x[, memo])
>
> Return a deep copy of x.

And as is stated:

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Meaning dictionaries hold references to different objects. In that case, you can alter one of them without ever worrying about the other. This function can be found in `copy` module:

```
import copy           # import this module for `deepcopy`

dic = {'a' : [1, 2]}
copy_dic = copy.deepcopy(dic)

dic['a'].append("spam")

print(dic)
print(copy_dic)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 'spam']}
{'a': [1, 2]}
```

However, in most cases a shallow copy is what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
copy_dic = dic
```

both `copy_dic` and `dic` point to the same dictionary (two references to same dictionary), so updating one will reflect in the other.

What you need is to create a copy of dictionary and whatever you change in the original dictionary is not going to reflect in the copy:

```
copy_dic = dic.copy()
```

---

```
dic = {'a': 1}

copy_dic = dic.copy()
dic['a'] = 3

print(copy_dic)
# {'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1: Case of Variable

Both `var_a` and `copy_var` are **`int`** object, which is **immutable**. When you do `var_a = 3`, **`var_a` points to a new memory address**. Here is the detailed explanation to your code:

`var_a = 1` : variable `var_a` points to the memory address of `1`

`copy_var = var_a` : variable `copy_var` points to the same memory address of `1`

`var_a = 3` : variable `var_a` points to the memory address of `3` while `copy_var` still points to the memory address of `1`

`print(copy_var)` : the result is `1` since the memory address of `var_a` is changed.

> 2: Case of Dictionary

Both `dic` and `copy_dic` are **`dictionary`** object, which is **mutable**. When you do `dic['a'] = 3`, **`dic` doesn't change its memory address and the content in the original memory address is changed**. Here is the detailed explanatioofto your code:

`dic = {'a':1}` : variable `dic` points to the memory address of `{'a':1}`

`copy_dic = dic` : variable `copy_dic` points to the same memory address of `{'a':1}`

`dic['a'] = 3` : `dic` doesn't change its memory address, the content in the original memory address is changed to be `{'a':3}`

`print(copy_dic)` : The result is  `{'a': 3}` since the content in the memory address is changed